# Error "Cannot read contents from file.." when changing themes from admin panel

Tags: magento2, theme

Error:

> Cannot read contents from file "C:/wamp64/www/magento2/" Warning!file_get_contents(C:/wamp64/www/magento2/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to change the theme in Website scope not Global.

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5666#issuecomment-233236951

Answer (score 11):

I have found a workaround for this issue. Please copy the folder

```
\vendor\magento\module-email\view\frontend\email
```

to

```
\vendor\magento\module-email\view\adminhtml\email\.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean & flush cache, remove generated files, and regenerate static content:

```
$ php bin/magento cache:clean
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
$ rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Report back if it does not fix the error.

Comment: I've got `cannot read contents from file web.css` and this solution work for me. Thanks